# SAP Crystal Reports multiple numeric range selection

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to create the report in SAP Crystal Reports (BusinessObjects CR 2013 SP5) which display a number of the records from the database. My record selection is based on the item number which goes from 0 to 9999999. If I want to select specific numeric range (i.e. between 2500000 to 2600000) I used following record selection formula:

```
{v_R_rvc_menuitem_fam_grp.menuitem_number} in ToNumber({@Start_ItemRng1}) to ToNumber({@End_ItemRng1});
```

where the `@Start_ItemRng1` is set to 2500000 and `@End_ItemRng1` is 2600000.

My problem is that I need to add second numeric range into the formula (records between 2700000 to 2800000). This way the report would returns records between 2500000-2600000 and 2700000 to 2800000. Unfortunately my all attempts returns with error code. Any suggestions how to correctly write the record selection formula?

Answer (score 0):

Create two new parameters called @Start_ItemRng2 and @End_ItemRng2. Then update your record selection formula to this...

```
{v_R_rvc_menuitem_fam_grp.menuitem_number} in ToNumber({@Start_ItemRng1}) to ToNumber({@End_ItemRng1})
OR
{v_R_rvc_menuitem_fam_grp.menuitem_number} in ToNumber({@Start_ItemRng2}) to ToNumber({@End_ItemRng2})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I used similar formula before (with additional parameters defined) but instead of "OR" between two statements I used AND. But that did not work. My understanding was that AND allows to process both statements at the same time, while OR would be to choose between two statements...obviously I was wrong!